# Debugger is not available in iOS extensions(iMessage) in Xamarin. Or is there a way to make it working?

Tags: ios, debugging, xamarin.ios, console, imessage

I am trying to debug the iMessage extension in Xamarin iOS project.I added the iMessage extension to my existing project and developing the extension project.
In my googling I found the debugging the iMessage Extension in Xcode from this link http://easynativeextensions.com/how-to-debug-your-ios-extension/
But It not worked in Xamarin.

I am unable to Debug the extension and even not able to see the application output(Console.WriteLine()).

Please provide steps to Debug/See Logs of iMessage Extension in the Xamarin iOS.

Thanks,
Harikrishna.

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, But working with out debugging.